# Joint distribution of integrals of diffusion and driving noise

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider a generic diffusion of the form
$$dX_t=f(t,X_t)dt+dB_t,$$
where $f$ is some *nice* function and $B_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

The marginal distributions of the integrals
$$I:=\int_0^TB_t~dt\qquad J:=\int_0^TX_t~dt$$
can in principle be computed with fairly straightforward methods:
$I$ is Gaussian by a [classical Riemann sum argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243925/integral-of-brownian-motion-is-gaussian),
and $J$ can (again, in principle) be computed by Feynman-Kac.

> **Question.** What about the joint distribution of $(I,J)$?

Are there general techniques that are well adapted to the solution of such problems? I'm also interested in any kind of nontrivial example where such computations have been made.

Comment: How does Feynman-Kac give the distribution of $J$?  In the form I am familiar with, it gives the expected value of J.

Comment: For example, in Wikipedia's formulation of F-K (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman-Kac_formula), I would set $f=0$, $\psi=1$, and $V(x)=\mu x$, and thus potentially obtain the Laplace transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the SDE:
$$
\begin{cases}
d X_t = f(t,X_t) dt + d B_t \\
d Y_t = d B_t
\end{cases}
$$
The infinitesimal generator of the process $(X_t,Y_t)$ is given by:
$$
L_t g(x,y) = f(t,x) \partial_x g(x,y) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{xx} g(x,y) + \partial_{xy} g(x,y) + \frac{1}{2} \partial_{yy} g(x,y) 
$$ Let $t_1$ and $t_2$ be real constants. At least formally, the solution to the PDE: 
$$
\partial_t u_t(x,y) = L_t u_t(x,y)+ (t_1 x + t_2 y) u_t(x,y)\;, \quad \left. u \right|_{t=0} = 1
$$ 
admits the stochastic representation
$$
u_t(x,y)= \mathbb{E}_x \left\{ \exp( t_1 I + t_2 J ) \right\}
$$ which we recognize as the *joint moment generating function* of $I$ and $J$.